# Access value of object from json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to access at value of key->value, 
this is my **var_dump** of `$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);`

```
array(8) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass) {
        ["key"]=> string(7) "address"
        ["value"]=> string(16) "via le mani dal "
    }
    [1]=> object(stdClass) {
        ["key"]=> string(21) "tempistica_in_vendita"
        ["value"]=> string(18) "Tra più di 3 mesi"
    }
}
```

how can I access to *"Tra più di 3 mesi"* asking the value of *tempistica_in_vendita* ?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve your result? Even pseudo code

Comment: If changing the input JSON is allowed, I would rather change the format, from `[ { "key": "address", "value": "via le mani dal" }, { "key": "tempistica_in_vendita", "value": "Tra più di 3 mesi" } ]` **to** `{ "address": "via le mani dal", "tempistica_in_vendita": "Tra più di 3 mesi" } ]`, this would makes things really simplier

Comment: Sure, I know, but I'm working only on backend and the front-end is not editable.
I've tryed with $data[1]->value and I get back my result. But I need to know if there are another way to specific the name of key and get the value without use the index

Comment: You need to loop through the array, find the first item where `key` is "tempistica_in_vendita", and return the value. If you're having trouble dealing with the objects, you can decode the json as arrays using `json_decode($_POST['data'], true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php) to access the value via the key. array_column can also work with objects.

```
$value = array_column($data,"value","key")["tempistica_in_vendita"];  
echo $value; //Tra più di 3 mesi
```

If further values are required, it is advisable to create an array $dataKeyValue:

```
$dataKeyValue = array_column($data,"value","key");
```